# Unexpected app pool restart - where to find reason of recycle

Tags: iis

We have an issue on the production server that is resulting in 503 Service Unavailable. Analysing issue we figured out that the app pool for our application is restarted more than expected (we have default recycle configuration, no special conditions just timed recycle every 29h, no idle timeout etc.)
I couldn't find any specific reason why would this happen, we couldn't find any exceptions prior to the unexpected recycle. Also, we can't find a specific reason why is this happening, we checked log, events in event viewer, but it doesn't hold too much info.
We also checked all common reasons for recycle, no config changes, no file changes, memory usage was inside limits, so there is no obvious reason for this behaviour.

So my question is:

How to check the reason behind pool recycle? Where to find information why recycle happened, is it scheduled to restart, or it's caused by some other rule, idling, or it's some external reason which is causing that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To log the recycle events, you need set logEventOnRecycle attribute as the proper value according to your requirement. You can check the following configuration reference to see the detailed information of the [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling/).

In IIS managerment console, you can take the following steps to set the value: Open IIS Manager -> Select the application pool you want configure -> Click Advanced Settings in the right actions pane -> Scroll down and find Recycling setings -> Expand the Generate Recycle Event Log Entry and configure the settings.

You can also use FRT to troubleshoot this issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Thanks, @DingPeng, I've already checked all configuration, and everything is turned on, by default, regarding the logging, my question is how to distinguish them in event logs, for me event logs are the same there are no information what caused the concrete recycle, can I get that info somewhere? Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. I don't have any visible issues or errors anywhere.

Comment: Have you used FRT to troubleshoot this issue？